# Query cache size in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, configuration

Is there a way to define/set/increase the query cache size in SQL Server 2014 similar to what MySQL has

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An administrator of the SQL Server can change the amount of cache memory available to the server.  So, that that extent you can influence the query cache size.

However, there is not a configuration to say "this much to the plan cache and that much to the buffer cache".  SQL Server dynamically manages the use of cache as needed to balance the pressure of plans and buffers.

There are ways that you can influence the reuse of cached files, such as 'forced parameterization', but that assumes that you really know your data.  (And that you trust your optimization over the SQL Server optimizer.)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server doesn't have any direct analog of MySQL's query cache, i.e. an in-memory cache of actual query results. Data and compiled query plans will be cached in memory, however.

If you've got a particularly expensive query with a lot of joins, you may want to look into creating an indexed view.